# set SPN on SQL cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, kerberos, spn

I have a question about how to manually set SPN for using Kerberos authentication on a SQL cluster.

Do I set one SPN on the clustername or one on each node?
[image]

I also have a default named instance, do i specify the name of the instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a SPN for a SQL FCI, use the FQDN of the FCI instance. For example, if the FCI name is "SQLFCI1" on the contoso domain and it listens on port 22000 with domain account SQLSvcAcct then the spn would be: `setspn -s MSSQLSvc/SQLFCI1.contoso.com:22000 Contoso\SQLSvcAcct`

If you don't want to deal with doing this by hand there is a [great tool provided by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046) for this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, just to be sure, in my case its: DBCLI01.domain.. as on the picture in my question?

Comment: Your picture doesn't show any pertinent information needed for the question. The domain is removed and we can't see the client access point in the FCI role (as nodes are on the screen).

Comment: Okey, where do I find the "SQLFCI1"-part in your reply? I have only masked the domain.

Comment: This is the network name that you would connect to. What do you type into SSMS to connect? What is the client access point name in the role in failover cluster manager for this installation of SQL Server. These will be the same value.

Comment: Perfect, got it!

Comment: I have a follow up question: What is the worst case senario if i configure the SPN wrong? Just that Kerberos wont be used or SQL server not starting?

Comment: @hanness worst case is you get errors and connections fail.